# How to split a query string for an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, split, query-string

I use cookies and query string to pass data from one page to another. Here is my code, I successfully encode URL string when button clicked.

```
$('#editListButton').click(function(){  

    var orderCookie = getCookie('ordercookie');
    var cookieArray = JSON.parse(orderCookie);

    for (i = 0; i < cookieArray.length; i++) { 
        urlString += cookieArray[i].toString();
    }

    window.location.href = "http://localhost:8888/abc.php?action=remove&value&=" + 
    encodeURIComponent(urlString);   //cookie value 

});
```

Final url is like below; 
http://localhost:8888/abc.php?action=remove&value&=6.25usd%20-%201%20Unit%20%20Ta%20Ft%20ItemA%20ItemB13usd%20-%202%20Unit%20Fiesta

On the other page, I'm trying to decode this url, I need separated items in an array. Elements of array should be;

array[0] = 6.25usd%20-%201%20Unit%20%20Ta%20Ft%20ItemA%20ItemB
array[1] = 13usd%20-%202%20Unit%20Fiesta

The code below run correctly only for the first element, actually I can not generate the array whatever I did. It gets whole url as only element. I need a way to split this url to put items into an array.

```
   <script>

        var action = /(?:\?|&)action=([^&$]+)/.exec(location.search);
        if ('remove' === action[1]) {
            var value = /(?:\?|&)value&=([^&$]+)/.exec(location.search);
            $('#defaultText').remove();
            for (i = 1; i < value.length; i++) { 
                alert(value[i]);
                $('#orderList').append('<p>' + value[i].toString().replace(/%20/g, " ")  + '</p>' + '<br>');
            }
        }  

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```js
var url = "http://localhost:8888/abc.php?action=remove&value&=6.25usd%20-%201%20Unit%20%20Ta%20Ft%20ItemA%20ItemB13usd%20-%202%20Unit%20Fiesta";
var res = decodeURIComponent(url.split(/\?|=/).slice(-1));
var idx = res.indexOf("B");
var arr = [];
arr.push(res.slice(0, idx + 1));
arr.push(res.slice(idx + 1));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: yepp, I think that is the solution thnks. I have a small problem, this code found "B" and split items using index of "B" (it is 36). It works perfect when I have 2 items to split but what if I have 4 or 5 items which have different lengths? I need a separator, I need to split items between commas for instance. How can I do?

Comment: It is a little bir complicated but I solved, thanks for your guidance. I'll add the code to answer.

Answer (score 1):

this code solved my problem.

```
            var url = location.toString();
            var res = decodeURIComponent(url.split(/\?|=/).slice(-1));
            var idx = [];
            var arr = [];
            var i = 0;
            var z = 0;

            do {
               z = res.indexOf("," ,z+1);
               if (z > -1){
                    idx[i] = z;
                    i++;
               }
            } while (z > -1)

            for (i = 0; i < idx.length; i++){
                if(i === 0){
                    arr.push(res.slice(0, idx[i]));  
                } else {
                    arr.push(res.slice(idx[i-1]+1, idx[i]));  
                }
            }

            $('#defaultText').remove();
            for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
                $('#orderList').append('<p>' + arr[i].toString() + '</p>');
            }
```